# Postgres - pg_proc toast table getting very large

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

The toast table size of our `pg_proc` table is getting very large -  439GB as of today. It seems to grow slowly over time.

As far as I understand, the `pg_proc` table just holds information about the functions that are available to use. Here is the direct quote from the docs:

> pg_proc stores information about functions (or procedures)

As far as I can tell it doesn't store anything any results or anything, so I am confused as to why the table is growing and why the toast table is so large. I can query the table and get back all the results in a few milliseconds, so the toast table doesn't even seem to be used.

We do have about 5 custom functions that are called by some triggers. Those functions make a call to `pg_notify`, which sends a small notification to the listeners of the notification channel. I figured something was being stored in `pg_proc` when those functions were called, but that doesn't seem to be the case since that is not what that table is for.

Is there any reason why this is growing that I might be missing?

Also, we are currently using Postgres 9.4 on RDS (AWS).

Comment: Is autovacuum enabled? Does `VACUUM FULL pg_proc` shrink the toast table?

Comment: Autovacuum is on. I have not yet run VACUUM FULL yet since that will lock up the table, and a plain VACUUM takes 6+ hours. I don't know enough about this table to know if having it locked up is going to effect everything else that is happening with the database.

Comment: Yeah, locking `pg_proc` will block all function calls (and even connection attempts, from the look of it). Though whatever the cause, I think you'll need to do this eventually if you want to reclaim that disk space.

Comment: Anyway, the only things I'd expect to write to `pg_proc` are `CREATE OR REPLACE`/`ALTER FUNCTION` and `GRANT`/`REVOKE` statements. But running any of these will duplicate the whole record (due to [MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html)), including the function body (which is presumably what's being toasted here). This seems consistent with the behaviour of your query, which won't pick up these old record versions.

Comment: Autovacuum should be cleaning them up, though... Any [prepared transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare-transaction.html) or old "idle in transaction" sessions hanging around? What does `VACUUM VERBOSE pg_proc` say about the toast table?

Comment: How big are the functions, and how often do you update them?

Comment: @NickBarnes We are using the Sequelize ORM, and using an upsert method that they expose - and in that method it looks like they are creating a pg function on the fly that includes all of the data we are upserting. This is almost definitely the cause of the huge toast table. Thanks for the insight! We are still not sure why the toast table is not being clearing out, however.